# How to render data as zero in empty dates in flot plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

I'm using flot with its time plugin to visualize some kind of user activities per day and i have data which looks like:
[[date, value], [date, value]]

Dates in UTC so everything works fine
but if where are no data between two dates flot doesn't recognize that data as zero and renders straight line.

For example i have data [[1 feb, 3], [3 feb, 3]] and it's renders like:
[image: i get]

And i want result like:

[image: i want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line charts are drawn from one point to the next, so what you have is the intended behavior. You have two choices to work around that:

1. Use a point or bar chart, then you have an empty space where points which zero values would be.
2. Add new points with zero values to the data, in your case something like
   `[[1 feb, 3], [2 feb, 0], [3 feb, 3]]`